# Ubuntu 20.04: some services fail during boot (files missing)

Tags: systemd, services, init, init.d

I have recently updated from 18.04x to 20.04.1 LTS. All seems to work fine, except that couple of services fail during boot.

Output of `systemctl --failed`:

```
● checkfs.service             loaded failed failed LSB: Check all filesystems.                     
● checkroot-bootclean.service loaded failed failed LSB: bootclean after checkroot.                 
● mountall-bootclean.service  loaded failed failed LSB: bootclean after mountall.                  
● mountall.service            loaded failed failed LSB: Mount all filesystems.                     
● mountdevsubfs.service       loaded failed failed LSB: Mount special file systems under /dev.     
● mountkernfs.service         loaded failed failed LSB: Mount kernel virtual file systems.         
● mountnfs-bootclean.service  loaded failed failed LSB: bootclean after mountnfs.                  
● mountnfs.service            loaded failed failed LSB: Wait for network file systems to be mounted
```

All the problems are related to missing files, for example:

a) output of `systemctl status checkfs.service`:

`checkfs.sh[1102]: /etc/init.d/checkfs.sh: 21: .: Can't open /lib/init/mount-functions.sh`

b) output of `systemctl status checkroot-bootclean.sh`:

`checkroot-bootclean.sh[1104]: /etc/init.d/checkroot-bootclean.sh: 17: .: Can't open /lib/init/bootclean.sh`

Those files (`mount-functions.sh` and `bootclean.sh`) are missing in `/lib/init`. And all other services seem to fail due to the fact that some files in `/lib/init` are missing (and thus some functions can't be called).

I have checked on another machine, and these services do not report any problems, yet the files are not present in the `/lib/init`. I thought that the services are disabled, but according to `systemctl list-unit-files` those services are enabled as well.

My system seem to be functioning properly, but it is just something I would like to fix.

What I tried so far:

1. At first I tried to find a package that provides missing files, but with no luck. When I discovered that same version of OS on another machine boots fine without those files, I realized this is not the right approach
2. I tried to 'cheat' and I have created empty files in `/lib/init` - some errors were fixed but some needed additional functions which can't be found (such as: clean_all in `/etc/init.d/checkroot-bootclean.sh` or `mount_run`, `mount_lock`, `domount` in `/etc/init.d/mountkernfs.sh`)
3. I commented out some of the lines in those services, and of course that seemed to work, but:

- I am not sure what is missing
- I am surprised that the same version of Ubuntu (20.04.1) works fine on another machine (even though there are no additional files in `/lib/init`)

I just do not know what to do next. I am pretty sure that I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems I have fixed the problem (with some help from my friend).

Steps:

I typed `dpkg -S checkroot` this resulted in the following:

```
mountall: /etc/init/checkroot-bootclean.sh.conf
initscripts: /etc/init.d/checkroot-bootclean.sh
mountall: /etc/init/checkroot.sh.conf
initscripts: /etc/init.d/checkroot.sh
```

This made me surprised, as I remember that `initscripts` package was only provided in Xenial. There is no reason for it to be still present on Focal.

Mountall (according to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mountall&searchon=all&suite=all&section=all) should also not be present in Focal.

So what I have done was:

```
sudo apt purge initscripts
sudo apt purge mountall
```

That removed a lot of files from `/etc/init.d` - many being those problematic ones, that gave me headaches.

I rebooted my machine.

The output of `systemctl --failed` is now as follows:

```
  UNIT LOAD ACTIVE SUB DESCRIPTION
0 loaded units listed.
```

Which is what I was aiming for.